# Default Bootstrap's 'input-sm' setting for crispy forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

Is there a way to set [Bootstrap 3's `input-sm`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#height-sizing) in `django-crispy-forms` globally (i.e. default setting)?

I searched the [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but apart from setting a `css_class` using Layout, I'm not really getting further.
I don't want to repeat all my field definitions.

Or is the recommended way to do this using a master CSS file?